# How to remove specific jQuery script from wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

A piece of jQuery is running on my wordpress site and I cannot for the life of me find it in the file structure to remove/modify it.

The initial problem is that a div in my PHP is not appearing in the DOM, I did however find this in the DOM:

```
<script>    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        jQuery( "#wpProQuiz_saveTemplate" ).closest( "div" ).remove();
        jQuery("select[name=templateLoadId]").closest( "div" ).remove();
    });</script>
```

My question is how can I remove it? Or maybe just break it? To stop it removing those two divs.

I can access the PHP so I could change the ID of the first one and the name of the second - but I don't know if that will cause problems.

My PHP/HTML is good but my Javascript/Jquery knowledge is pretty non-existent. Can I insert a new script tag that would remove, break or reverse this one?

Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the PHP or HTML that contains this jQuery?

Comment: why can't you just find the `.php` file that contains that piece of jQuery and then remove it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? or is it hosted on localhost?